# How can we create some pages password protected in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to secure some of my pages with a username and password, so that no-one can access those pages without logging in. Only Registered users can view those pages. And we also want to put registration form for users to enter his/her basic details. Once user registered his details will be saved in database and sent mail to admin.

Could you please suggest me any plugin, or suitable information for making this application?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress comes with a builtin user management feature. You can create Roles and then assign specific users to these roles. You can then use a plugin (there are several) to manage what those users can or cannot see. Here is one.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capa/